# I need a "Quick as fox and Lazy as dog" text-Editor for my web development practice

Tags: text-editor

I was learning from Lynda.com some courses on web development.  I noticed they were using MacOS and as text Editor Text Mate.  It's was simple, light weight and quick to launch, even no multi-tab(I hate multi-tab in text edit).  I kinda love it.  I work in Windows 10. Since now, I was using default Notepad and Aptana Studio for IDE.  But working in Notepad kinda hard as it doesn't highlight any markup or notifies the syntax errors.  Some of my friends recommended Notepad++, so I tried it.  But it isn't quick as fox or lazy as the dog(not-smart)! Most annoying is on restarting it opens last opened tab.  For some people it's helpful, I had to close all the files before starting my work, even thought the tab sizes very small.

I tried "Similar text editor like TextMate" in google but it returned some most rated like Sublime, Notepad++, etc. So I came here. People guys help finding a very good texteditor which should be faster like notepad and easy-to-handle.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it, but for a short learning curve I would suggest https://atom.io/ based on what I've heard about. Works on any OS, powerful as is, and customizable.

When you outgrow that editor and are ready to learn a better one, I suggest emacs, the editor I do use. (Well, emacs includes an editor....) It does take longer to learn, but once you make the investment it's worth it. I'm still learning more ways it can make my life easier, still growing into it instead of outgrowing it. That said, vim / gvim can also be a solid choice. No matter which one you choose, the main thing is to take time to learn it, explore the nooks and crannies of what your tool offers, and customize it so it feels like it's helping you, not like you're barely wrestling it into submission.

Comment: Thanks, trying out Atom.

Answer (score 0):

For simple text editor I just use Sublime Text, it's light, and does the job well! That's what I would recommend.

Comment: But would it start quick like default NotePad on windows?

Comment: Oh yes, it's start up time is unoticable. It's just as light as NotePad but has more tools and is smarter.

Comment: But doesn't open multiple instances when hiding the tabs!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your previous comment?

Comment: In notepad, when I open another file, it creates an instance and open in it. But in sublime when I chosen the 'Hide the Tabs' option, it opens new file in same window. opening another instance is helpful! I need multiple windows opened side by side neither multi-tabs nor opening files in same window closing the last one.

Comment: Okay, yea, that's a mac only feature defined as `"open_files_in_new_window": true` but it is unfortunately not available on windows. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you use the text editor for coding while on a Windows environment, even if the code doesn't run there, then I recommend EditPad, which has been around for 20+ years or so with active development.  Its shareware version is only a slightly stripped down version of the licensed one, too, so there's that.

If you're on Linux, of course, it's merely a matter of emacs vrs. vim.